# Как совместить типы float и range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Разбираю некоторые практические задания по Python, одно из них гласит: Для заданного положительного вещественного числа A необходимо найти минимальное целое число K, при котором выполняется неравенство: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Понакидал со своими практически *нулевыми знаниями* следующий **код**:

```
a = float(input())
k = 2
while 1+range(0, 1/k) <= a:
    k+=1
print(k)
```

Но, к моему сожалению, получил **ошибку**:

```
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Оказалось, типы range и float **несовместимы**, что и прописано в официальной документации языка. Встал логичный вопрос: есть ли какие-то **обходные пути**, по которым можно их подружить и/или представить этот же код другим способом?

Comment: Когда-то я тоже сталкивался с такой проблемой,попробуйте использовать модуль numpy.

Comment: Вы хотите увеличить диапазон на `1`? Тогда просто сгенерируйте его на `1` больше (прибавив к правой границе), вместо попытки складывать с числом: `range(0, 1/k + 1)` (кстати, если диапазон с `0`, то можно написать просто `range(1/k + 1)`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
a = float(input('Введите A > '))
m = 0.
k = 1
while m <= a:
    m += 1/k
    k += 1
print('K >', k)

# Проверим полученный результат. Посчитаем сумму ряда до K-того элемента и выведем её
t = 0
for i in range(1, k+1):
    t += 1/i
print('Сумма ряда >',t)
```

Входные данные:

```py
Введите A > 5
```

Результат:

```py
K > 84
Сумма ряда > 5.013973034584928
```

Answer (score 4):

Вы просто плохо понимаете, что такое range и как он работает.

Во-первых, range возвращает некоторую последовательность чисел. Вы пишете

`1+range(0, 1/k)`

Как можно сложить число с последовательностью чисел?

Очевидно, вы хотели сложить число с СУММОЙ последовательности, но тогда и нужно писать

`1 + sum(range(0, 1/k))`

Но и здесь тоже есть ошибка.

`range(a, b)` возвращает члены арифметической прогрессии от `a` до `b`. У вас же ряд, который не является арифметической прогрессией. Соответственно, с помощью только `range` вашу последовательность не сгенерировать.

Ну а как посчитать то, что вы хотите, правильно, уже написал Евгений.